# Failed assertion: line 3927 pos 14: '_dependents.isEmpty': is not true

Tags: dart, flutter

I am back again with the issue related to the question already posted by me on stack overflow [Error: '_elements.contains(element)': is not true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728408/error-elements-containselement-is-not-true/46770966#46770966)

this issue has been plaguing me but i was unable to reproduce the same issue and now i have somehow tried to repro again and I have posted the code for everyone to figure out what is it that i am doing wrong that's throwing up this assertion error and crashing the app.

I am new to programming and any help would be greatly appreciated. I have trimmed down the code and I am aware of the some of the bugs. But, the only main concern is the `Failed assertion: line 3927 pos 14: '_dependents.isEmpty': is not true.` and `Failed assertion: line 1766 pos 12: '_elements.contains(element)': is not true.`

Steps to reproduce.

> main.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:untitled1/addnewbranch.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    new MaterialApp(
      home: new Branches(),
    ),
  );
}

class ProjectModel {
  BranchSetUpModelData branchesModel;
  ProjectModel(this.branchesModel);
}

class BranchSetUpModelData {
  String branchName;
  String hostelType;
  String area;
  String city;
  BranchSetUpModelData(this.branchName, this.hostelType, this.area, this.city);
}

DatabaseReference _branchesRef;
List<ProjectModel> projectModel = new List();
Map data = {};

List<String> mapKeys = new List();

DataSnapshot dataSnapshot;

class Branches extends StatefulWidget {
  //const BranchView({ Key key }) : super(key: key);
  const Branches({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _BranchesState createState() => new _BranchesState();
}

class _BranchesState extends State<Branches> {
  String userUid = '';
  String text;
  int noOfBranches = 0;
  int itemCount;

  Future<Null> getUserUid() async {
    try {
      //FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
      //userUid = user.uid;
      //print(userUid);
      _branchesRef =
          FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('data').child('branches');
      print('branchesref = $_branchesRef');

      if (_branchesRef != null) {
        try {
          _branchesRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snapShot) {
            dataSnapshot = snapShot;
            print(snapShot is Map);

            print(dataSnapshot.value);
            data = dataSnapshot.value;
            print(data is Map);
            print(data);

            data.forEach((key, value) {
              mapKeys.add(key);
            });
            print('no of branches = $noOfBranches');
            projectModel.clear();
            mapKeys.forEach((value) {
              _branchesRef.child(value).once().then((DataSnapshot b) {
                data = b.value;
                data.keys.forEach((k) {
                  BranchSetUpModelData x = new BranchSetUpModelData(
                    b.value['branchDetails']['branchName'],
                    b.value['branchDetails']['hostelType'],
                    b.value['branchDetails']['area'],
                    b.value['branchDetails']['city'],
                  );
                  print('details from for each loop');
                  ProjectModel projectModelData = new ProjectModel(x);

                  projectModel.add(projectModelData);
                });
                print('projectmodel length = ${projectModel.length}');
              });
            });
            setState(() {
              noOfBranches = mapKeys.length;
              itemCount = noOfBranches;
            });
            print('no of branches = $noOfBranches');

            data.keys.forEach((k) {
              print('inside this foreach loop');
              print(k);
            });
          });
        } catch (Exception) {
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              child: new AlertDialog(
                  content: new Text(Exception.message.toString())));
        }
      } else {
        print('user does not exist');
      }
    } catch (Exception) {
      print(Exception.toString());
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          child: new AlertDialog(
            content: new Text(Exception.toString()),
          ));
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    mapKeys.clear();
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.setPersistenceCacheSizeBytes(10000000);
    getUserUid();
    /*setState((){
      noOfBranches = mapKeys.length;
    });*/
    print('noOfBranches in init state= $noOfBranches');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('noof branches inside widget build = $noOfBranches');
    //if(noOfBranches!=0) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Branches',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primaryColor: const Color(0xFF229E9C),
      ),
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: const Text('Branches'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal[300],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          heroTag: 'branchesHeroTag',
          child: new Icon(Icons.add),
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal[300],
          onPressed: (() {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              new MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => new AddNewBranch(),
              ),
            );
          }),
          tooltip: 'Add Branch',
        ),
        body: new Container(
          child: new ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 4.0,
              right: 4.0,
            ),
            itemCount: itemCount,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              if (noOfBranches != 0) {
                // children: <Widget>[

                return new InkWell(
                  onTap: (() {
                    /*Navigate here to a different page*/
                  }),
                  child: new Card(
                    child: new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Container(
                          //margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top:16.0),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
                          child: new Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Expanded(
                                child: new Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    new Container(
                                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            left: 16.0,
                                            right: 8.0,
                                            top: 4.0,
                                            bottom: 4.0),
                                        child: new IconButton(
                                            icon: new Icon(Icons.call),
                                            onPressed: (() {}))),
                                    new Container(
                                      child: new Text(
                                        '80/125',
                                        style: new TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 18.0,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              new Expanded(
                                child: new Row(
                                  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                  children: [
                                    new Container(
                                      margin:
                                          const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
                                      child: new Text(
                                        projectModel[index]
                                            .branchesModel
                                            .hostelType,
                                        style: new TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 18.0,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        new Container(
                          margin:
                              const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 8.0, 16.0, 4.0),
                          child: new Row(children: <Widget>[
                            new Text(
                              projectModel[index].branchesModel.branchName,
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 24.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ]),
                        ),
                        new Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 16.0, right: 16.0, bottom: 8.0),
                          child: new Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Text(projectModel[index].branchesModel.city),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ); // InkWell ends here so this has to go into ListView.builder
              } else {
                itemCount = 1;

                return new Center(
                  child: new Column(
//            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Text(
                        'Setup your Hostel',
                        style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 24.0,
                          color: Colors.grey[400],
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      new Text(
                        'Please click below + icon to Setup your Hostel',
                        style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                          color: Colors.grey[400],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
          ), // ListView.builder ends here.
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> globals.dart

```
library my_app.globals;
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
```

> addnewbranch.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:untitled1/main.dart';
import './globals.dart' as gl;

class BranchSetupModel {
  String branchName;
  String hostelType;
  String area;
  String city;
  BranchSetupModel(this.branchName, this.hostelType, this.area, this.city);
}

BranchSetupModel branchSetupModel =
    new BranchSetupModel('', 'Hostel Type', '', '');

class AddNewBranch extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddNewBranch({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new _AddNewBranchState();
  }
}

class _AddNewBranchState extends State<AddNewBranch> {
  String actionsString = 'Next';
  String userUid;

  TextEditingController _branchNameController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _areaController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _cityController = new TextEditingController();

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  bool _formWasEdited = false;
  bool _autovalidate = false;
  String dropDownvalue = 'Hostel Type';

  //FocusNode _branchManagerNameFocusNode = new FocusNode();

  String _validateName(String value) {
    _formWasEdited = true;
    if (value.isEmpty) return 'Name is required.';
    final RegExp nameExp = new RegExp(r'^[A-Za-z ]+$');
    if (!nameExp.hasMatch(value))
      return 'Please enter only alphabetical characters and spaces.';
    return null;
  }

  Future<Null> getUserUid() async {
    try {
      FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
      userUid = user.uid;
      print(userUid);
    } catch (Exception) {
      print(Exception.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserUid();
    _branchNameController =
        new TextEditingController(text: branchSetupModel.branchName);
    _areaController = new TextEditingController(text: branchSetupModel.area);
    _cityController = new TextEditingController(text: branchSetupModel.city);
    dropDownvalue = branchSetupModel.hostelType;
    branchSetupModel = new BranchSetupModel('', 'Hostel Type', '', '');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
      ),
      title: 'Branch Setup',
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: const Text('Add New Branch'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal[300],
          leading: new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: (() {
              print('back button clicked');
              //to be removed and to include functionality here
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (_) => new Branches(),
                ),
              );
            }),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new Center(
              child: new Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new FlatButton(
                    child: new Text(
                      actionsString,
                      style: new TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      print('Save button clicked');

                      String pushKey = gl.databaseReference
                          .child('data')
                          .child('branches')
                          .push()
                          .key;
                      gl.databaseReference
                          .child('data')
                          .child('branches')
                          .child(pushKey)
                          .child('branchDetails')
                          .set({
                        "branchName": branchSetupModel.branchName,
                        "hostelType": branchSetupModel.hostelType,
                        "area": branchSetupModel.area,
                        "city": branchSetupModel.city,
                        "pushKey": pushKey
                      });
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        new MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (_) => new Branches(),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    splashColor: const Color(0xFF229E9C),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: new Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: new ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
                child: new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text('Hostel Type'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              new Container(
                //height: 56.0,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
                child: new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new DropdownButton<String>(
                      //key: _dropDownKey,
                      hint: new Text(dropDownvalue),

                      items: <String>[
                        'Mens',
                        'Womens',
                      ].map(
                        (String value) {
                          return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            value: value,
                            child: new Text(value),
                          );
                        },
                      ).toList(),
                      onChanged: (String value) {
                        setState(() {
                          dropDownvalue = value;
                          branchSetupModel.hostelType = value;
                          print(branchSetupModel.hostelType);
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              new Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
                child: new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Expanded(
                      child: new TextField(
                        autocorrect: false,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Branch Name',
                        ),
                        controller: _branchNameController,
                        onChanged: (String value) {
                          branchSetupModel.branchName =
                              _branchNameController.text;
                          print(branchSetupModel.branchName);
                        },
                        //validator: _validateName,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              new Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
                child: new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Expanded(
                      child: new TextField(
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Area/Location',
                        ),
                        controller: _areaController,
                        onChanged: (String value) {
                          branchSetupModel.area = value;
                          print(branchSetupModel.area);
                        },
                        //validator: _validateName,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              new Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 16.0,
                  right: 16.0,
                ),
                child: new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Expanded(
                      child: new TextField(
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'City',
                        ),
                        controller: _cityController,
                        onChanged: (String value) {
                          branchSetupModel.city = value;
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> pubspec.yaml

```
name: untitled1
description: A new Flutter project.

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_sign_in: ^1.0.1
  firebase_analytics: ^0.1.1
  firebase_auth: ^0.3.1
  firebase_database: ^0.1.2
  firebase_storage: ^0.0.7


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
```

Please integrate the firebase app to run the code before trying to reproduce the error and make sure the read and write access set to 'true' as I have not added any authentication.

As far as I know the error only occurs in the main.dart file.It works fine for a few times and then the errors start coming in. First, it throws up the error `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0` this error is for the `ListView.builder()` and then the other two assertion errors come up.

Please can someone tell me what I am doing wrong or is there a different way to achieve the same goal without these errors.

> output from flutter doctor command.

```
    [√] Flutter (on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063], locale en-GB, channel alpha)
    • Flutter at C:\Users\Prayuta\flutter
    • Framework revision e8aa40eddd (3 weeks ago), 2017-10-17 15:42:40 -0700
    • Engine revision 7c4142808c
    • Tools Dart version 1.25.0-dev.11.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Prayuta\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-27, build-tools 27.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01)

[√] Android Studio (version 3.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2017.2)
    • Flutter plugin version 18.4
    • Dart plugin version 172.4343.25

[√] Connected devices
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 7.1.1 (API 25) (emulator)

Process finished with exit code 0.
```

Answer (score -6, accepted):

One of my colleague actually changed the way I've built my ListView.builder and I am not seeing the error now. I'll keep an eye on this and post any new ways to answer this question or any errors creeping up again.

I only changed the main.dart file which I have posted for reference.

> main.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:untitled1/addnewbranch.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    new MaterialApp(
      home: new Branches(),
    ),
  );
}

class ProjectModel {
  BranchSetUpModelData branchesModel;

  ProjectModel(this.branchesModel);
}

class BranchSetUpModelData {
  String branchName;
  String hostelType;
  String area;
  String city;

  BranchSetUpModelData(this.branchName, this.hostelType, this.area, this.city);
}

DatabaseReference _branchesRef;
List<ProjectModel> projectModel = new List();
Map data = {};

List<String> mapKeys = new List();

DataSnapshot dataSnapshot;

class Branches extends StatefulWidget {
  //const BranchView({ Key key }) : super(key: key);
  const Branches({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BranchesState createState() => new _BranchesState();
}

class _BranchesState extends State<Branches> {
  String userUid = '';
  String text;

  Future<Null> getUserUid() async {
    try {
      //FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
      //userUid = user.uid;
      //print(userUid);
      _branchesRef =
          FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('data').child('branches');
      print('branchesref = $_branchesRef');

      if (_branchesRef != null) {
        try {
          _branchesRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snapShot) {
            dataSnapshot = snapShot;
            print(snapShot is Map);

            print(dataSnapshot.value);
            data = dataSnapshot.value;
            print(data is Map);
            print(data);

            data.forEach((key, value) {
              mapKeys.add(key);
            });

            projectModel.clear();
            mapKeys.forEach((value) {
              _branchesRef.child(value).once().then((DataSnapshot b) {
                data = b.value;
                setState(() {
                  data.keys.forEach((k) {
                    BranchSetUpModelData x = new BranchSetUpModelData(
                      b.value['branchDetails']['branchName'],
                      b.value['branchDetails']['hostelType'],
                      b.value['branchDetails']['area'],
                      b.value['branchDetails']['city'],
                    );
                    print('details from for each loop');
                    ProjectModel projectModelData = new ProjectModel(x);

                    projectModel.add(projectModelData);
                  });
                });
                print('projectmodel length = ${projectModel.length}');
              });
            });

            data.keys.forEach((k) {
              print('inside this foreach loop');
              print(k);
            });
          });
        } catch (Exception) {
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              child: new AlertDialog(
                  content: new Text(Exception.message.toString())));
        }
      } else {
        print('user does not exist');
      }
    } catch (Exception) {
      print(Exception.toString());
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          child: new AlertDialog(
            content: new Text(Exception.toString()),
          ));
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    mapKeys.clear();
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.setPersistenceCacheSizeBytes(10000000);
    getUserUid();
    /*setState((){
      noOfBranches = mapKeys.length;
    });*/
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //if(noOfBranches!=0) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Branches',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primaryColor: const Color(0xFF229E9C),
      ),
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: const Text('Branches'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal[300],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          heroTag: 'branchesHeroTag',
          child: new Icon(Icons.add),
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal[300],
          onPressed: (() {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              new MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => new AddNewBranch(),
              ),
            );
          }),
          tooltip: 'Add Branch',
        ),
        body: (projectModel.length == 0)
            ? new Center(
                child: new Column(
//            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text(
                      'Setup your Hostel',
                      style: new TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 24.0,
                        color: Colors.grey[400],
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    new Text(
                      'Please click below + icon to Setup your Hostel',
                      style: new TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        color: Colors.grey[400],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            : new Container(
                child: new ListView.builder(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 4.0,
                    right: 4.0,
                  ),
                  itemCount: projectModel.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    // children: <Widget>[

                    return new InkWell(
                      onTap: (() {
                        /*Navigate here to a different page*/
                      }),
                      child: new Card(
                        child: new Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Container(
                              //margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top:16.0),
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
                              child: new Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new Expanded(
                                    child: new Row(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        new Container(
                                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                left: 16.0,
                                                right: 8.0,
                                                top: 4.0,
                                                bottom: 4.0),
                                            child: new IconButton(
                                                icon: new Icon(Icons.call),
                                                onPressed: (() {}))),
                                        new Container(
                                          child: new Text(
                                            '80/125',
                                            style: new TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 18.0,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  new Expanded(
                                    child: new Row(
                                      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                      children: [
                                        new Container(
                                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                              right: 16.0),
                                          child: new Text(
                                            projectModel[index]
                                                .branchesModel
                                                .hostelType,
                                            style: new TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 18.0,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            new Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                  16.0, 8.0, 16.0, 4.0),
                              child: new Row(children: <Widget>[
                                new Text(
                                  projectModel[index].branchesModel.branchName,
                                  style: new TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 24.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ]),
                            ),
                            new Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 16.0, right: 16.0, bottom: 8.0),
                              child: new Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new Text(
                                      projectModel[index].branchesModel.city),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ); // InkWell ends here so this has to go into ListView.builder
                  },
                ), // ListView.builder ends here.
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this will help everyone who is struggling with the same use case to solve their problem,
Many Thanks.
Mahi.

Comment: Please mention specifically what you have changed. We are unable to identify what was the actual change in your main.dart file.

Comment: For anyone wondering, here's a diff https://www.diffchecker.com/j3ukAZV9
2 noticable things are ternary op in MaterialApp>home>body and new setState((){})

Comment: This is quite wrong.. you are calling `setState` in a loop, and all of that is in a function which is called from `initState`. If this code works for you, it is a miracle!

Answer (score 28):

I recently had the same exception when I was trying to navigate to another route from a Stateful Widget. Turns out I had forgotten to add the line `super.initState();` at the start of my widget's `initState()`

Once I change it to this it worked perfectly

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ....
  }
```

Comment: i solve this problem with convert  StateFullWidget to stateLessWidget

Comment: For me it was simply the order - before I had it at the end of the initState method. Moving it to the top fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 10):

This error happens due to incorrect widget configuration, so in other words it's not an error itself, but a symptom of another error.

**For OP**

OP has already found a solution so I won't elaborate on it. Fixing the error in your `ListView` should do the trick.

**TL;DR**

Try:

- Calling `super.initState()` inside all your `StatefulWidgets.initState()` overrides.
- Making sure all your `Widget.key`s are unique.
- Making sure all your widgets that use a `builder` function have no errors. These widgets include `AnimatedBuilder`, `LayoutBuilder`, and external packages like `GetX` or `Provider` that have a builder, and any packages that depend on them (like `Bloc`). With these `builder` widgets, the exception usually occurs when you build the same `Widget` with different `instance members` based on some passed value. For example:

```
...
BlocBuilder<MyBloc, MyState>(
  builder: (context, state) => Container(
    color: state is SomeState ? Colors.blue : Colors.red, // Something along these lines
  ), 
)

// or
BlocBuilder<MyBloc, MyState>(
  builder: (context, state) => state is SomeState ? Container(color: Colors.red) : Container(color: Colors.blue), 
)
....
```

**More Explanation**

First of all, I want to note that while the exception message is a bit misleading, the flutter team had a couple `TODO`s to make the exception clearer and refer specifically to the faulty widget.

As the message mentions, the error is related to duplicate `GlobalKey`s within the widget tree. Usually, this doesn't happen due to directly using the same `Key` on two different widgets (because devs are usually aware of that). Instead, it hides itself behind other issues such as the ones mentioned above. They all produce similar effect, however: They cause errors in the widget's lifecycle state.

Forgetting to call `initState`, for instance, messes up the widget's lifecycle state update. I'm not exactly sure exactly where this happens, but it seems that the framework creates duplicate element/widget to the same widget with the same `GlobalKey` if the widget's lifecycle state is tampered with. **This needs further investigation and confirmation**.

The thing with `builder` widgets is that if the first widget to be returned from the `builder` has an exception, the framework will mount it, but for some reason, the lifecycle change will not occur when the second widget to be returned from `builder` is inserted in the tree, and both the first and the second widgets end up with the same `Key`.

In both cases, when the framework unmounts currently active widgets, it checks widgets' lifecycle state, determines which ones are inactive, and ignores them. However, because lifecycle states of some widgets are wrong, it might treat an inactive widget as active, compare it to currently active widgets only to find duplicates, and then throw the exception.

If you want to check that yourself, you can read `src/widgets/framework.dart` file referred to in the error message, starting from `BuilderOwner.finalizeTree()` function.

Comment: Unique Widget.key works for me

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who may find this helpful, I recently had this issue too and it was caused by incorrectly setting a number of `key` parameters in a list of widgets. I was setting the key based on an id:

```dart
key: Key(item.id.toString())
```

However due to some other logic `item.id` can sometimes be null and because there are a number of these widgets I ended up with multiple widgets with the key: `Key("null")`. Updating my key to ensure it was unique solved my problem:

```dart
key: Key(items.indexOf(item).toString())
```

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me as I wrapped a `ListView.builder` with an `Expanded` without a container surrounding the `Expanded` directly as the `body` of my `Scaffold`.

Answer (score 0):

For me I was declaring my form key inside the initState(). I just moved out as a global variable and it work.

This is my initSatate() now:

```
@override 
void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: If your code contains only `super.initState();` then you can remove the whole override (these three lines) completely, and everything will still work well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had define a component with static key, and I used the component 3 times inside a ListView. So Flutter was find a problem with the position of some components, because the Flutter search by key to verify changes. To solve my problem, I put the property key as optional.

Before:

```
MyTextField(
      {Key key = const Key("textField"),
      this.label,
```

After change:

```
MyTextField(
      {Key? key,
      this.label,
...
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using provider and GetX both then this error occurs some time and app crash.
Remove one of them if both not neccesory

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was popping a route in which I was passing arguments like this to fix another problem (this was more of a dummy argument), once I removed the arguments, the problem went away

```
onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context)
                    .pushNamed(EditProductScreen.routeName, arguments: {''});
              }),
```

In the above remove 'arguments : {''}

Answer (score -1):

In my case i was using a modalBox. So i created another form key and used it with it. Thats how i solved mine

Answer (score -2):

In my case, the issue was a `form` i was using in two different screens, while declaring its `key` **before** the widget itself, statically. Moving the `key` declaration in the state solved the issue.